# Upload Progress doesn't show when on HTTPS

Tags: javascript, php, ssl, upload

This code I'm using for uploading files is working fine, it shows the progress and does the job... but when I use it on my web server with HTTPS (SSL) the file is uploaded, but the progress is not showed... if I switch back to HTTP, the progress appears... anyone got an idea?

// INDEX.PHP

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
/* Script written by Adam Khoury @ DevelopPHP.com */
/* Video Tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EraNFJiY0Eg */
function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("file1").files[0];
    // alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file1", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "upload.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);

    console.log('INIT');
}
function progressHandler(event){
    console.log('PROGRESS', event);
    _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
    _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
}
function completeHandler(event){
    console.log('COMPLETE', event);
    _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
    _("progressBar").value = 0;
}
function errorHandler(event){
    console.log('ERROR', event);
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}
function abortHandler(event){
    console.log('ABORT', event);
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTML5 File Upload Progress Bar Tutorial</h2>
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
  <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
  <h3 id="status"></h3>
  <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

// UPLOAD.PHP

```php
    $fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
    $fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
    $fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
    $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true


    if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
        echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
        exit();
    }


    if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "test_uploads/$fileName")){
        echo "$fileName upload is complete";
    } else {
        echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
    }
```

// SERVICE WORKER:

```
var CACHE_STATIC_NAME = 'pensadigital-estatico-v21';
var CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME = 'pensadigital-dinamico-v21';

// Static cache
const statiAssets = [
    '/',
    '/index.php',
    '/biblioteca/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js',
    '/biblioteca/js/jquery.form.min.js',
    '/biblioteca/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js',
    '/biblioteca/js/scripts.js',
    '/biblioteca/js/formularios.js',
    '/biblioteca/templates/base/material_azul/jquery.fancybox.css',
                            '/biblioteca/templates/base/material_azul/estilos.css','/biblioteca/templates/fonte/roboto_condensed/fonte.css',    '/biblioteca/css/estilos.css'
]

// Install SW
self.addEventListener('install', async event=>{
    //console.log('[Service Worker] instalando SW');
    event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_STATIC_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('[Service Worker] Fazendo cache estatico');
        cache.addAll(statiAssets);
      })
    )
})

// Remove old cache files
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Activating Service Worker ....', event);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys()
      .then(function(keyList) {
        return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
          if (key !== CACHE_STATIC_NAME && key !== CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME) {
            console.log('[Service Worker] Removing old cache.', key);
            return caches.delete(key);
          }
        }));
      })
  );
  return self.clients.claim();
});


// FETCH REQUESTS
self.addEventListener('fetch', event=>{

    url_solicitacao = event.request.url;

    // se a solicitação é de um vídeo, apenas repassar para cliente
    if ( url_solicitacao.indexOf('.mp4') > 0 || url_solicitacao.indexOf('.mp3') > 0 ){

        //console.log('[SW] Vídeo, passar direto: ', url_solicitacao);
        return;


    // Se é uma imagem, adotar estratégia de cache first depois network
    }else if ( url_solicitacao.indexOf('.jpg') > 0 || url_solicitacao.indexOf('.jpeg') > 0 || url_solicitacao.indexOf('.png') > 0 || url_solicitacao.indexOf('.gif') > 0 ){

        event.respondWith(
            caches.match(event.request)
                .then(function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    return response;
                } else {
                    return fetch(event.request)
                    .then(function (res) {
                        return caches.open(CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME)
                        .then(function (cache) {
                            cache.put(event.request.url, res.clone());
                            return res;
                        })
                    })
                }
                })
        );


    // qualquer outro conteúdo, adotar estratégia de network first depois cache
    }else{

        event.respondWith(
            fetch(event.request)
                .then(function(res) {
                    return caches.open(CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME)
                            .then(function(cache) {
                                cache.put(event.request.url, res.clone());
                                return res;
                            })
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    return caches.match(event.request);
                })
        );

    }

});
```

Comment: What do you see in your browser console? What does network inspector show you? Does your site have a valid and trusted certificate?

Comment: It doesn't show any errors on console... I did a test and disable the Service Worker on the site, and it works.. so I'm thinking there is something about the cache fetching that does that.... I'm updating the code with my service worker code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it... I just make a change on my Service Worker code to ignore POST requests, like this:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
    //This is the code that ignores post requests
    if (event.request.method === "POST") {
        return;
    }

    // the rest of the code
});
```